# I almost have a page numbering with comments but something fails with mounted (vue.js)

Tags: vue.js

Here you have the HTML:

```
<div>
        <nav>
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li @click.prevent="paginaAnterior"><a href="#">Anterior</a></li>
                <li @click.prevent="contenidoPagina(pagina)" v-for="pagina in totalPaginas()" class="page-item"><a href="#">{{ pagina }}</a></li>
                <li @click.prevent="paginaSiguiente"><a href="#">Siguiente</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <article class="caja__articulo-noticias" v-for="item in datosPaginados">
            <p>
                {{ item.nombre }} {{ item.fields.Nombre }} {{ item.apellido }} {{ item.fields.Apellidos }}
            </p>
            <p>
                {{ item.comentario }} {{ item.fields.Comentario }}
            </p>
        </article>
 </div>
```

And this is the vue.js. I would like to show the first page of the comments when the website is loaded

```
mounted: function () {
    this.obtenerDatosNoticia2();
    **this.contenidoPagina(1);** // it doesn´t shows me the first page
},
methods: {
    totalPaginas: function () {
        return Math.ceil(this.infosNoticia2.length / this.elementosPorPagina);
    },
    contenidoPagina: function(numeroPagina){
        this.paginaActual = numeroPagina;
        this.datosPaginados = [];
        let inicio = (numeroPagina * this.elementosPorPagina) - this.elementosPorPagina;
        let fin = (numeroPagina * this.elementosPorPagina);
        this.datosPaginados = this.infosNoticia2.slice(inicio,fin);
    },
    paginaAnterior: function () {
        if(this.paginaActual > 1) {
            this.paginaActual = this.paginaActual - 1;
        }
        this.contenidoPagina(this.paginaActual);
    },
    paginaSiguiente: function () {
        if(this.paginaActual < this.totalPaginas()) {
            this.paginaActual = this.paginaActual + 1;
        }
        this.contenidoPagina(this.paginaActual);
    }
}
```

})

To put you in context I'm doing a blog about music. I have a section with news about music, singers... and at the bottom I've made a kind of number pagination to list all the comments that people can add. The number pagination works right, the problem is that I'd like to see the first page of the comments when you're in this section because I only see the number pagination (1, 2, 3, 4...) and you've to click in each one to see the comments.

Comment: Can you add more details about what is broken and what you're trying to achieve? And it shouldn't affect your code at all but the spaces after `this. ` feel really weird

Comment: Sure! I've updated it at the bottom. Thank you!!!